# Java - Eclipselink - memory leak

Tags: java, jpa, memory-leaks, eclipselink

I have a JBoss EAP 6.4 on Eclipselink 2.6 on Oracle application, that after some time dies with out of memory. Looking at a heap dump in MAT it looks as if all entities were kept in memory forever.

[image]

I have set

```
<shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
```

so I'd assume that entities live only during a transaction, but not so.

What's the trick to make Eclipselink forget the entities?

Comment: Are you using container manager transactions or you manage transactions manually? Maybe you open up a transaction and do not close it at some point

Comment: I would not assume this is an EclipseLink issue ,or that some setting will make the problem disapear without more information - the most common causes are people statically holding onto entities or EntityManagers and not releasing them.